# how we can choice some group's element

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have 3 columns in my data set like this:

```
    Household     person     activity
        1           1          home
        1           1          school
        1           1          shopping
        1           1          home
        1           2          home
        1           2          work
        1           2          home
        2           1          home
        2           1          work
        2           2          home
        2           2          school
        2           2          home
```

the first column is the number of household. the second column is number of persons in that household and third column is the activity of that person.

a set of activities for a person is home based if the first and last activity of that person is home.

Is there any way to drop household whose at least the activities of one of the member is not home based? 
In above example the activity of all members in the first household is hom-based but in second household the activity of first person is not home based (home ---> work) so I wanna drop second household.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can first create a `temp` variable to mark `person` whose `first` and `last` `activity` is `"home"`, then select those `"household"` whose `all` `temp` values are `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Household, person) %>%
  mutate(temp = first(activity) == "home" & last(activity) == "home") %>%
  group_by(Household) %>%
  filter(all(temp)) %>%
  select(-temp)

#  Household person activity
#      <int>  <int> <fct>   
#1         1      1 home    
#2         1      1 school  
#3         1      1 shopping
#4         1      1 home    
#5         1      2 home    
#6         1      2 work    
#7         1      2 home
```

---

Using same logic we can also use base R `ave`

```
df[with(df, ave(as.logical(ave(activity, Household, person, FUN = function(x) 
         x[1L] == "home" & x[length(x)] == "home")), Household, FUN = all)), ]
```

---

To know which `Household` are selected or dropped we can do

```
df %>%
  group_by(Household, person) %>%
  mutate(temp = first(activity) == "home" & last(activity) == "home") %>%
  group_by(Household) %>%
  summarise(selected = all(temp))

#  Household selected
#      <int> <lgl>   
#1         1 TRUE    
#2         2 FALSE
```

Comment: how I can see which household has been dropped?

Comment: @sherek_66 Updated the answer for that.

Comment: Thanks! it works, just could you plz tell me how I can make a vector with this true and false?

Comment: just `pull` the values. `df %>%
  group_by(Household, person) %>%
  mutate(temp = first(activity) == "home" & last(activity) == "home") %>%
  group_by(Household) %>%
  summarise(selected = all(temp)) %>% pull(selected)`

Comment: what is name of this vector?

Comment: I have 50000 household, so I need to store true,false

Comment: @sherek_66 assign it to a variable. `temp_var <- df %>% group_by(Household, person) %>% mutate(temp = first(activity) == "home" & last(activity) == "home") %>% group_by(Household) %>% summarise(selected = all(temp)) %>% pull(selected)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table` methods to do thiss.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Household', 'person', create a logical vector based on the 'home' values in the `first` and `last` 'activity' column, then grouped by 'Household', if `all` the values in the logical vector is TRUE, filter the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, ind :=  first(activity) == "home" & last(activity) == "home",
     .(Household, person)][, .SD[all(ind)], Household][, ind := NULL][]
#   Household person activity
#1:         1      1     home
#2:         1      1   school
#3:         1      1 shopping
#4:         1      1     home
#5:         1      2     home
#6:         1      2     work
#7:         1      2     home
```

---

If we need to have the 'selected' as logical summarised column

```
setDT(df)[, .(selected = all(diff(.SD[, .I[unique(activity[c(1, .N)]) ==
           "home"], person]$V1) == 1)), .(Household)]
#  Household  selected
#1:         1  TRUE
#2:         2 FALSE
```

and to get the expected output from above

```
setDT(df)[df[, .I[all(diff(.SD[, .I[unique(activity[c(1, .N)]) == 
         "home"], person]$V1) == 1)], .(Household)]$V1]
#    Household person activity
#1:         1      1     home
#2:         1      1   school
#3:         1      1 shopping
#4:         1      1     home
#5:         1      2     home
#6:         1      2     work
#7:         1      2     home
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Household = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), person = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L), activity = c("home", "school", "shopping", "home", 
"home", "work", "home", "home", "work", "home", "school", "home"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```